# Sending Parse Push Notification via website

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I've been using Parse for years to send Push Notifications to my iOS apps and its been working great.

I now want to be able to do the same thing - but from my own web page.  Meaning, I wanna just go to a regular web page (which I'll create), type some text into a textfield, press a button - and have that text get sent as a Push Notification to my iOS App.

I’ve tried the following code - no luck so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PN TEST</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

Parse.initialize("xxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

function makePushNotification() {
    alert ('sending a push!');

    $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           headers: { 'X-Parse-Application-Id’ : ‘xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx’ , 'X-Parse-REST-API-Key’ : ‘xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' },
           url: "https://api.parse.com/1/push", data: '{"channel": "",   "data": {"alert": "Sending a Push Notification from my web page."} }',
            contentType: "application/json"
        }); 
}


</script>

</head>


<body>
    Enter your push notification: <br/>

    <form id="testForm">
        <textarea cols="60" rows="4" id="textAreaText"></textarea>
            <br/>
        <input type="button" value="Send Push Notification" onclick="makePushNotification()" />
            <br/>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

(Obviously I'm hard-coding the actual text of the Push Notification here and not really reading it from the `textarea` box - but that's just for right now.)

Anyway, any ideas what this is missing?

Answer (score 0):

contentType: "application/json" should be a header.

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
```

Comment: you mean it should go in the `headers` section of the JSON up above it? meaning in here: `headers: { 'X-Parse-Application-Id’ : ‘xxxxxxxxxxxxx`...` ?

Comment: I did what you suggested and got this error: `[Error] Failed to load resource: Request header field contentType is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. (push, line 0)`

Comment: @Sirab33 It should be 'Content-Type' like I have in my answer.